# Selaginella plant dying - care and maintenance tips

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations

I received the Selaginella plant back in March and I've been watering it each 2nd day. (Recommendation from the florist) Also, if I would skip more than 3 days without watering it the plant's leaves would go down lifelessly :) So, I continued watering it little by little each 2-3 days.

Slowly parts of the plant started to turn brown and dry off. So, a month ago I added a bit of general fertilizer in the water, thinking that I would make it better, but instead half of the plant started to turn brown and dry off.

I started reading about ways to care for this type of plant and put her in the shade (no direct sunlight).  Another option was to give her more humidity.
Therefore, I bought a big glass jar and planted what was left of it in there, to create the humid space. Weeks later the plant doesn't seem to get better - continuing to turn brown and dry slowly.

Any tips on how to fix it? I really love this plant and seeing it slowly dying is heartbreaking :(

Thank you in advance!  (pics of before and after below)

[image]

[image]

[image]